# Remove Object from List C++

Tags: c++, list

lot of questions like this are there but i tried most of them but i couldn't success. as my last try i came up without any errors but the function does not work

this is what i did last i need to remove the specific object from list

```
void discharge_patients() {
    string str;
    cout << "Enter Patients Name : " << endl;
    cin >> str;

    for (hospital const& common : hospitalList) {
        if(common.getPatientName() == str){
            cout << "\nPatient Name : " << common.getPatientName() << "\t";
              hospitalList.remove(common);
              break;
        }
    }
    iputData();
}
```

declaration of hospitalList

```
list<hospital> hospitalList;
```

this is how i add objects to `hospitalList`

```
void admit_patient() {
    hospital obj;
    string str;
    int val;
    cout << "Enter Patients Name : " << endl;
    cin >> str;
    obj.setPatientName(str);
    cout << "Enter Bed Number : " << endl;
    cin >> val;
    obj.setBedNum(val);
    cout << "Enter Date of Admit 'dd/mm/yyyy' : " << endl;
    cin >> str;
    obj.setDateOfAdmit(str);
    cout << "Enter Patient Age :" << endl;
    cin >> val;
    obj.setAge(val);
    cout << "Enter Patient Ward No :" << endl;
    cin >> val;
    obj.setWardNumber(val);
    //push the object to hospitalList
    hospitalList.push_back(obj);
    iputData();
}
```

this is how my `hospital` class looks like

```
class hospital {
```

public:
    string Patient_Name, Date_of_Admit;
    int Bed_Num, Age, Ward_Number;

```
int getAge() const {
    return Age;
}

void setAge(int age) {
    Age = age;
}

int getBedNum() const {
    return Bed_Num;
}

void setBedNum(int bedNum) {
    Bed_Num = bedNum;
}

const string& getPatientName() const {
    return Patient_Name;
}

void setPatientName(const string& patientName) {
    Patient_Name = patientName;
}

int getWardNumber() const {
    return Ward_Number;
}

void setWardNumber(int wardNumber) {
    Ward_Number = wardNumber;
}

const string& getDateOfAdmit() const {
    return Date_of_Admit;
}

void setDateOfAdmit(const string& dateOfAdmit) {
    Date_of_Admit = dateOfAdmit;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator becomes invalid if you change the list during iteration.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10360466/5107799 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016332/5107799

Comment: To add to that point, instead of using a for-loop, consider calling `std::find()` from `<algorithm>`. This way you avoid manipulation while iterating.

Comment: Or simply `remove_if` from the second link

Comment: Yes, but OP's goal is still to remove. So by getting the iterator from `std::find()`, as long as it isn't `hospitalList.end()`, they can just call `remove()`. Moreover, if the iterator is at the end of the list, then OP can conclude that record isn't in `hospitalList`.

Comment: for the second link how can i merge my condition `if(common.getPatientName() == str){`